# Summing or aggregating a column of items based on two columns with similar vectors in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I need to aggregate rows that have similar items in two columns, please. Is there an "or" function to do this please? I have posted a sample dataset below:

```
A1 <- data.frame(Animal1= c("A", "A","B","B","D") ,Animal2=c("B","D","D","A","B"),Frequency=c(2,3,1,4,5))
> A1
  Animal1 Animal2 Frequency
1       A       B         2
2       A       D         3
3       B       D         1
4       B       A         4
5       D       B         5
```

How do I aggregate so that I only get one value combining the frequencies on rows 3 and 5 where Animal1 is B and Animal2 is D on row 3 and Animal1 is D and Animal2 is B on row 5 giving a frequency of 6?

Comment: Hello Joke O. Were the answers below helpful with your problem? If not, would you provide feedback and what the expected output is?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution. I may be over-complicating it, but it should give you the desired result. The first thing that I did was make it so that the strings were not factors in the dataframe.

```
A1 <- data.frame(Animal1= c("A", "A","B","B","D"), Animal2=c("B","D","D","A","B"), 
                 Frequency=c(2,3,1,4,5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

A1 %>% 
  mutate(combined = map2_chr(Animal1, Animal2, ~paste0(sort(c(.x, .y)), collapse = ""))) %>%  
  group_by(combined) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(Frequency))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  combined total
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 AB           6
2 AD           3
3 BD           6
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood your question but is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% as_tibble %>% 
  filter((Animal1 == "B" & Animal2 == "D") | (Animal1 == "D" & Animal2 == "B")) %>% 
  summarise(sum_freq = sum(Frequency))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, guys. In addition to @StephenK's answer, I added another step to split the new "combined" column.

```
A1 <- data.frame(Animal1= c("A", "A","B","B","D"), Animal2=c("B","D","D","A","B"), 
             Frequency=c(2,3,1,4,5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

A2<- as.data.frame(A1 %>% mutate(combined = map2_chr(Animal1, Animal2, ~paste0(sort(c(.x, .y)), collapse = ""))) %>%  
group_by(combined) %>% summarise(total = sum(Frequency)))

#create new columns for each letter
A2$Animal1 <- substr(A2$combined, start = 1, stop = 1)
A2$Animal2 <- substr(A2$combined, start = 2, stop = 2)
A2
  combined total Animal1 Animal2
1       AB     6       A       B
2       AD     3       A       D
3       BD     6       B       D

##Select only columns needed and reorder
A3 <- A2[,c("Animal1","Animal2", "total")]
A3
  Animal1 Animal2 total
1       A       B     6
2       A       D     3
3       B       D     6
```